# sticky or pinned sectioned list view in android with dynamic data

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-listview, listview-adapter

I want to achieve something like [this](https://ibb.co/gWrPyvL). I am getting "survey titles"(type: string) and "different number of questions"(type:string) under every survey titles. I want to use **survey titles as headers** and **questions of that survey should be display under that survey title header**.

I have already tried https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders; and few other libraries. It is using first char of list data as header. Which in my case not possible.

[*This*](https://ibb.co/3N33Xyy) will be the look one header and its questions. When there are multiple survey with their questions, Sticky or pinned Header behaviour I want to achieve in my android app.

Comment: So you tried using a char. What about a single character string? Those libraries work.

Comment: @Mr00Anderson I have a complete string, I can't go with one char to decide the heading! I need a way by which I can just cover all questions of that survet title in which survey title is displayed as heading in ui.

Comment: Where the code you tried that didn't work in any library. It helps to post the samples you tried with what libraries, so others do not have to scour the internet for API references. [This here looks like you can customize it more then a Char](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders#getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the API for StickyListHeaders how you want and not use a char. I took this sample and changed a few items [StickyListHeaders#getting-started](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders#getting-started) indicated by my comments "`//*** NOTE:`" Just have to learn that you can change implementations however you want in Java if the API is provided. Just takes experimenting. Nothing in this API forces you to use their 'char' method or method at all. This is just the build in API I assume.

```
 @Override 
    public View getHeaderView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        HeaderViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new HeaderViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, parent, false);
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (HeaderViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        //*** NOTE: You can use the name here
        //set header text as first char in name
        String headerText = "" + countries[position].subSequence(0, 1).charAt(0);
        holder.text.setText(headerText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public long getHeaderId(int position) {
        //*** NOTE: You could use the hashcode of the word here or your own implementation
        //return the first character of the country as ID because this is what headers are based upon
        return countries[position].subSequence(0, 1).charAt(0);
    }
```

Comment: My ultimate goal is to achieve this: I have n number of heading list array, and all that n headers have m number of questions; I want to make n header; m questions in each header underlying them.  Can you give me ultimate guide about what changes I have to made in this code? It will be a great help from your side.

Comment: So honestly their API should be enough. This is what [the sites about](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292175/what-is-the-purpose-of-stack-overflow).  Giving answers to exact problems. You said you had a problem. I showed you how to complete that task using a API. You just need to experiment. That apart of being a software developer.

Comment: Mr00Anderson thank man. I have solved this. What I have done is I have made an object of the section as well as its questions. So that I can work with both through a one single entity.